# How to mock route.snapshot.params?

Tags: angular, angular-test

In my Angular 4 component I have something like:

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myId = this.route.snapshot.params['myId'];
}
```

And I'm trying to create a mock that suppose to look like follows:

```js
class MockActivatedRoute extends ActivatedRoute {
  public params = Observable.of({ myId: 123 });
}
```

My test fails with:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined.

How do I suppose to mock it? Have I misunderstood the proper usage of `ActivatedRoute` and should better use `router.subscribe` in my component? I saw some complicated examples where people mocked snapshot itself, however for me it looks overcomplicated.

---

The test itself is quite simple:

```
describe('ngOnInit', () => {
it('should set up initial state properly',
  () => {
  const component = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent).componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.myId).toEqual('123');
  });
});
```

If I simply change a method under the test to something like follows - the test works:

```
ngOnInit() {
    //this.myId = this.route.snapshot.params['myId'];
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.myId = params['myId'];
    });
}
```

Obviously I need to mock Activated snapshot, but is there a better approach?

Comment: I also tried to do something like `const fakeRoutes: Routes = [{path: 'info', data: { catalogId: '123' }, component: StatusComponent},]` and then `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(fakeRoutes)`. Not sure if this  syntax is supported trhough.

Comment: Are you trying to use this in unit testing? If so can you post that code

Comment: You are getting params of undefined because your mock is mocking the params observable `this.route.params` (returns an observable) instead of the snapshot `this.route.snapshot.params` (returns an object of the params)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. snapshot also uses params, so I thought it should be smart enough to understand that I mocked params. That means if I wanted to mocks both snapshot and params I would need to copy&paste params twice. Anyway, I've managed to resolve it yesterday, thanks for you help.

Answer (score 52):

Ok, I've found how to mock ActivatedRoute snapshot in the simple way. Something like this works for me:

```
providers: [MyComponent, {
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
  useValue: {snapshot: {params: {'myId': '123'}}}
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 41):

If using route.snapshot.paramMap.get( 'uuid' ) instead:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, convertToParamMap } from '@angular/router';

{
    provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue:
        { snapshot: { paramMap: convertToParamMap( { 'uuid': '99-88-77' } ) } }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks! Otherwise there is a `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get is not a function` error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer save my day.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of faking it, you can retrieve original route and simply spy on params

```
   let route: ActivatedRoute;

        beforeEach(() => {
          TestBed.configureTestingModule(...).compileComponents();

          route = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
   })

   it("test",  () => {
      const spyRoute = spyOn(route.snapshot.paramMap, "get")
       spyRoute.and.callFake((paramNameToRead) => {

        switch (paramNameToRead) {
            case "id" : {
                return "value1";
            }
            case "foo" : {
                return null;
            }
            case "bar" : {
                return baz;
            }

        }


    });
```

}